# Making two squares with :before class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make two squares before my headings. I know how to make a single square with the before class, but I dont know how to make two that isn't the same width.

What I'm going for is something that looks like this:

[image: What I'm going for]

Comment: What browsers do you have to support? Only the latest ones or old ones also?

Comment: using `::before` can be the solution and for two borders you can do this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/yaymzrdn).

Comment: @bjarkofj see my answer below, but you can access the after pseudo element as well.

Comment: @Harry - Preferably all browser.

Comment: @bjarkof: In that case, use a thicker `border-left` than `border-right` for the element. (*Edit:* Just like what Nilesh Mahajan has posted).

Comment: @bjarkof, do you happen to know what versions of the browsers you won't be supporting?

Comment: @Harry I'm also going to be using his solution as it is the simplest! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply a `:before` as this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8se6e01/1/) does.

**HTML**

```
<h1>Reference</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1{
    font-size: 24px;
    color:blue;
}
h1:before{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:30px;
    width:5px;
    border-left:solid 10px blue;
    border-right:solid 5px blue;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: this is great! although, I don't think i would float the before pseudo element, have you tried just making it an `inline-block` instead?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very simple way to achieve what I want, so I'm gonna go with this solution!

Comment: @bjarkof: if it works you can mark my answer as accepted!

Comment: @Seed: I have modified my answer as per your comment. thanks for improving it :)

Comment: @NileshMahajan Since you updated the CSS to being inline-block instead, it isn't placed horizontally centered, with the heading as it is in your fiddle. Are there any way to achieve this, with the inline-block version also? :)

Comment: @bjarkof: yes there is one work around you can add `vertical-align:top;` to the :before element CSS

Comment: @NileshMahajan Awesome! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @bjarkof: welcome mate!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to also to create the after pseudo element. Let me know if the code below helps.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #A0CD62;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
h1:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  border-left: 0.5em solid $color-pistashio;
  border-right: 0.25em solid $color-pistashio;
}
```

```html
<h1>Referencer</h1>
```

Comment: Why do we need :after? this can be achieved by using :before only. and OP has asked for :before

Comment: @Nilesh Mahajan, your answer is also doable, the only thing i would change is to un-float it and `inline-block` the element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! :)

Comment: @seed: thanks for your suggestion! I appreciate it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.square {background-color:green; width:100px; height:100px;}

.square:before {content:""; background-color:white; position:absolute; width:20px; height:100px; left:50px; }
```

```html
<div class="square">

    </div>
```

Just change the colour from green to brighter green :D.

Basically what i did there is. Created a big green div with green background. Then using ':before' added white content on the top of it which has the same height as the div.

This should work .

Please , let me know if that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with only the :before sudo class. Here's a quick pen of it working with both :before and :after. You should be able to monkey about with it to suit your needs.  http://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/epgeNQ

```
.logo {
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  left: 50px;
}
.logo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.logo:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Why don't you just create an svg of the logo?

Comment: Actually Nilesh has nailed this. well done, I hadn't thought to use border

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The reason I don't use svg is because it is headings :)